# Convert list of symbols to character string in own function

Tags: r, tidyeval, quosure

I have the following data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(time   = runif(20),
                  group1 = rep(1:2, times = 10),
                  group2 = rep(1:2, each = 10),
                  group3 = rep(3:4, each = 10))
```

I'm now writing a function `my_function` that takes the following form:

```
my_function(data, time_var = time, group_vars = c(group1, group2))
```

If I'm not mistaken, I'm passing the group_vars as *symbols* to my function, right?

However, within my function I want to first do some error checks if the variables passed to the function exist in the data. For the time variable I was successful, but I don't know how I can turn my group_vars list into a vector of strings so that it looks like `c("group1", "group2")`.

My current function looks like:

```
my_function <- function (data, time_var = NULL, group_vars = NULL)
{
  time_var          <- enquo(time_var)
  time_var_string   <- as_label(time_var)
  group_vars        <- enquos(group_vars)

  # is "time" variable part of the dataset?
  if (!time_var_string %in% colnames(data))
  {
    stop(paste0("The variable '", time_var_string, "' doesn't exist in your data set. Please check for typos."))
  }
}
```

And I want to extend the latter part so that I can also do some checks in the form of `!group_vars %in% colnames(data)`. I know I could pass the group_var variables already as a vector of strings to the function, but I don't want to do that for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

`enquos` is the wrong function here: it operates on multiple arguments, but you’re only passing a single argument. Just use `enquo`. However, either way the result isn’t directly usable, because you don’t get a vector of unevaluated names — you get an *unevaluated `c` call*.

Working with this is a bit more convoluted, I’m afraid:

```
group_vars_expr = quo_squash(group_vars)
group_var_names = if (is_symbol(group_vars_expr)) {
    as_name(group_vars_expr)
} else {
    stopifnot(is_call(group_vars_expr))
    stopifnot(identical(group_vars_expr[[1L]], sym('c')))
    stopifnot(all(purrr::map_lgl(group_vars_expr[-1L], is_symbol)))
    purrr::map_chr(group_vars_expr[-1L], as_name)
}
stopifnot(all(group_var_names %in% colnames(data)))
```

Comment: Phew, ok, this looks indeed a bit more complex than I had hoped for. Would you have any recommendation how to circumvent this situation? i.e. it might be necessary to pass the group vars as c("...", "...") to the function after all?

Comment: One simple workaround is to pass these parameters inside `...` instead of a named parameter. Then you can use `ensyms(...)`, which ensures that only symbols are valid, and the user calls the function as `my_function(data, time_var = time, group1, group2)`. This may not be to your liking, however, and it does make the function call somewhat less readable.

Comment: @deschen See updated answer, I fixed the issue with the correctness check, since it was fairly trivial after all (and I fixed two unrelated copy & paste errors).

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's generally bad practice to inspect quoted code in this way. One way to take multiple variables in a named argument is to take a list of expressions created with `vars()`. The other way, which would work here, is to take _selections_. I have added an answer to illustrate the latter approach.

Comment: @LionelHenry I haven’t made this very clear in my answer (at least not in the current version) but I agree. It’s complex, brittle and thus error-prone. Your answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use `c()` in this way, chances are you need *selections*. One easy way to take selections in an argument is to interface with `dplyr::select()`:

```
my_function <- function(data, group_vars = NULL) {
  group_vars <- names(dplyr::select(data, {{ group_vars }}))
  group_vars
}

mtcars %>% my_function(c(cyl, mpg))
#> [1] "cyl" "mpg"

mtcars %>% my_function(starts_with("d"))
#> [1] "disp" "drat"
```